# Export executable jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to export executable in eclipse. I do all steps but when i execute the .jar, it show my first layout but when my program has to close the first layout and open other, all the program close.

I exported the same project to ZIP and I execute from there and run fine.

TRACE running in terminal:

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!    at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)     at
>   vista.initbarcos.initialize(initbarcos.java:96)   at
>   vista.initbarcos.access$0(initbarcos.java:65)     at
>   vista.initbarcos$1.run(initbarcos.java:52)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

FIX:

I have problem with bufferedImage i change for URL i do this with all... and now work fine. TY all.

Comment: Check the manifest file in the jar and verify all the classpath if its correct. there maybe some reference to folder you are missing out.

Comment: What's the stack trace? Run your application from Command Prompt (on Windows) or Terminal (on other OSs) to get a stack trace.

Comment: I post the trace Robin.

Comment: Following the trace i saw that my jar have problem with BufferedImage and i change it for URL and work... I dont know why..

Comment: @user1736258 If you have your answer, add it as an answer to this question and accept it to remove this question from the Unanswered list.